Feedback resistor package selection for DC-DC converter
I'm working on the following circuit to make 1.8V@3A from 5V input.
Would you please let me know what should be the feedback resistor package for the feedback circuit (R16 and R17)? (I'm considering to use 0805 package)


Can you explain why the resistor package selection is important? R16 and R17 will have less than 1V across them and dissipate micro watts so can't see that the voltage or power rating of the resistors is significant.

@Chester Gillon thank you for your comment, i wanted to make sure the package can deliver enough power for the feedback circuit, so I assume even 0402 would be enough, if the power is uW?

You could use any package which can handle more than a milliwatt and can widerstand one Volt across it. I can't think of an resistor which wouldn't fullfill this requirement...
Look for what is avaible for you and keep in mind that you should use precise (1% or less) resistors since you finetune a voltage.
Looking a that the datasheet, your Power Good pullup resistor seems in the wrong place and has a way to low value


thanks for the answer, based on the datasheet I can see this: Power good open drain output pin. A pull-up resistor can be connected to any voltage less than 6V. Leave it open if it is not used. what do you suggest for the PG pullup resistor value?

@Andromeda I would suggest 499k as the datasheet recommends and connecting it to Vout, since Vout should never be over 6V by design.

thank you very much, I changed it based on the datasheet, would you please also vote on my question?
